# How to cause EF to build update SQL with string concat?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 / EF 5 web application's database I have a table with a Comments column that I want to concat new comments to. In traditional T-SQL, I'd write:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Comments = 'Hi' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + Comments WHERE ID = 2
```

I find with method linq for EF (uow + repository pattern -- which I regret), I have to first query the current value of Comments and prepend my new comments to it:

```cs
StringBuilder displayComment = new StringBuilder();
var item = uow.MyRepos.Where(i => i.ID == 2);
item.Comments = displayComment.Append("Hi")
                              .Append(Environment.NewLine)
                              .Append(item.Comments)
                              .ToString();
uow.Save();
```

Is there any way to write this update without needing to query the DB?  I'd like to somehow get EF to generate the t-sql above. The comments can be lengthy and I don't care about what it contains.  Performance is a concern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I add this here as a comment, because it's not an answer: you're right about what EF can do, and how to do it. However, if you need to do something that EF doesn't support, you don't need to spend energy on trying to get it done. You can simply execute a custom query or stored procedure to solve your problem. It can look less smart, but I don't think it is. There are many things that EF can't do, but *you are allowed* to do things in other way, instead of trying to implement magic or hacky solutions for your problem. The same problem arises with mass updates or deletes. The solution is simple

Comment: Thank you for saying this @JotaBe -- I was trying to stay within the lines, but sometimes that isn't the best solution.

Comment: @LoJo you said ***I'd like to somehow get EF to generate the t-sql above*** - so that's why your question has been upvoted to ***5*** (at the time I wrote this). Otherwise it's just a normal requirement, nothing special and even not an answer need to be added. You should have understood about that with some comment and deleted the question right away.

Comment: @Hopeless -- I decided to go a different way, but others can still benefit from your suggestion and the work you put into it.

Comment: in fact using raw SQL query in this case is what we should do, my answer is just for showing how it could be done according to your requirement. It's of course not recommended, the only value here is about intercepting command before EF actually executes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard update sets the field, and I assume that you will need to keep that functionality, otherwise you will not be able to edit previous comments. So that means you have a special update case. I would add a method to the repository for `MyTable` that runs the sql you want:

```
public int PrependComment(int id, String comment)
{
   String sql = "UPDATE MyTable SET Comments = {0} + 
      CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + Comments WHERE ID = {1}";
   return dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, comment, id);
}
```

Comment: Thank for this.  I lost sight of doing things the direct way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you can play with is using a `DbCommandInterceptor`. You can intercept every non-query-executed command (update, delete, insert) and modify the command text before it's actually being executed. The code here is just for understanding how it could be done. You can refactor it for more convenient usage:

```
public class PrependTextInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{        
    const string table = "MyTable";
    const string column = "Comments";
    public override void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        command.CommandText = Regex.Replace(command.CommandText, 
                              string.Format(@"(?i:(?<=^UPDATE \[.+\]\.\[{0}\]\r\nSET .* \[{1}\] = ).+?(?=(,|\r\n)))", table, column), "$& + " + column);            
        base.NonQueryExecuting(command, interceptionContext);            
    }
}

//Usage
DbInterception.Add(new PrependTextInterceptor());
//after this every time you set the Comments property 
//it will be understood as prepending    
item.Comments = displayComment.Append("Hi")
                              .Append(Environment.NewLine).ToString();
```

Just one more note, If you load your `item` normally, its `Comments` property should also be loaded. So you lose the benefit of not loading it first before prepending. I think you need to use `Attach` in which you just need to know the `ID` to be able to update it without loading it (like as via a query `context.Set<MyTable>().Single(e => e.ID == 2)`, `Comments` then should be ***surely loaded***).

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  I've decided to go with a combination of @JotaBe and Colin's recommendation, but I think others might find it very helpful.